# PaperJS - increase vector magnitude

Tags: javascript, vector, paperjs

Sorry, the question was ill conceived. What I meant is:
I have 2 points that form a segment. And then I want to place a segment at an angle of x degrees of the first segment. How would I go along to calculate the position of the third point?

Basically it's this diagram: 
[Diagram](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0LD9OaUw9-EcWg5TVdMOW5mQ00) **edited the link, should work now**

I know the magnitude of OB, and BC, and the OBX angle and I need to find the length of OC and the COB angle.

I've tried the triangle math, but somehow it fails to produce the desired output. Is there a better way to do that? I'm a bit clueless, skipped too many math classes. :(

**Previous Question (not really valid):**
Any idea how i can increase the length of a vector in paperjs?
If I do it directly, the angle naturally changes, so I need a way to increase it's length to a specific amount, while keeping the initial angle. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you increase the length directly? The proper way to do it is to multiply by a number bigger than one: `aPoint = aPoint * aFloat` or `aPoint = aPoint.multiply(aFloat)`. The angle should not change when you do so.

Comment: http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/q1bKS8xNVbJSCs5OLUnOUNJRSs5PAfETFWwV8lLLFQLyM/NKNIx0zDRj8pLz84rzc1L1cvLTNRL1EvPSc1IxRHNLc0oyC3IqNUxNNaFKgIYmFaUmZheAjCpWsoqOrQUA

Comment: I cannot view the document you linked to.

Comment: I've updated the link, my bad.

Comment: Given the diagram this isn't a paper question - it's just geometry and/or trigonometry. It takes multiple steps but you can find the vertical length that completes the triangle for which OB is the hypotenuse. From there you can construct another right triangle for which BC is the hypotenuse, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an answer to the question you meant to ask, but the correct way to increase the length of a vector is to set the length of the point. See the sketch:

[sketch.paperjs.org](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/q1bKS8xNVbJSCs5OLUnOUNJRSs5PAfFj8hIVbBXyUssVAvIz80o0DA10FAwNNK1j8pLz84rzc1L1cvLTNRJ1FBL1clLz0ksyQFJATVAeUK+hgQF+1UDLkopSE7MLQBYUK1lFx9YCAA==)

And here is the reference explaining the length of a point (maybe not intuitive in a pure geometry sense):

http://paperjs.org/reference/point/#length